# File System for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, filesystem

I am new to Ubuntu & want to dual boot my Windows 7 laptop.
I am confused as to which file system should be used for the Ubuntu drive.
Some people say `FAT32` is must while some say `EXT4` is better.
I am absolutely new to this EXT4 file format.
So will a file created in Ubuntu with EXT4 open in Windows 7 with `NTFS` vice versa?
Sorry if this is a very basic doubt.
Also is EXT4 efficient than NTFS (I know that FAT32 is pathetic compared to NTFS for large sized drives).

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be *ext4* for Ubuntu, and *ntfs* for Windows. *ext4* partitions cannot be read on Windows, but both *ext4* and *ntfs* can be read and written from Ubuntu.

My suggestion would be to create native *ext4* partition for Ubuntu, and store shared files on Windows *ntfs* partition.

Current setup for my dual boot laptop:

```
Partition O/S     Mount point

ext4      Ubuntu  /
ext4      Ubuntu  /home
ntfs      Windows c:
ntfs      Windows d:
```

As you already realized, drive D (4th partition) is shared between Ubuntu and Windows. I have added it to `/etc/fstab` so this partition automatically mounts to `/windows` folder.

NB: Since this question is not about optimal partitioning, let's skip all the talks about how to partition for Linux.

You want to keep your home directory so your ubuntu settings (.bashrc/various configs) are independent of your install, that way, if you bork your ubuntu, or ever just feel the need, you can just re-install ubuntu while keeping your settings. The reason you want another NTFS partition is because, as many people nowadays, you carry around lots of platform non-specific data (i.e.: movies,audio..etc) putting all that sort of data there enables you to get at it from either boot environment.

Comment: Hi Andrejs Thank You for your answer.
I should keep the amount of space for my Ubuntu drive allocated before installation right?
& then when do I format the drive with format ext4?
which application is recommended for formatting the drive to ext4 format?

Comment: Ubuntu installation will do this for you! Sure, you need to have a space to create partitions. Be accurate if you already have *ntfs* partition on your drive, and don't want to lose it. Backup! And yes, all partitions are fixed sized, including *ext4*, so you need to specify it's size (unless you will rely on Ubuntu installation automatic partitioning, which is ok as well).

Comment: I want to allocate 100GB for Ubuntu on my Laptop.
What I meant was that should just keep 100GB Unallocated space & Ubuntu will give me option to format that space into a drive; or should allocate 100GB space in Windows & format that to a drive & then specify that drive while installing Ubuntu?

Comment: BTW why are there 2 ext4 partitions on your lalptop?
& what is that Mount point & why is it different for both Partitions?
& in which partition did you install Ubuntu?
Thank You.

Comment: A lot of people like to keep a separate partition for their personal files but there is no need to `/home` is where your personal files are kept.  Andrejs has chosen  to make this a separate partition and '/' is the rest of the file system.  There is no need to do this but it can make it easier to backup or when you decide to upgrade.

Comment: Correct. Also, regarding allocating the space for partitions - don't create any partitions and format them, just leave that space totally unallocated - Ubuntu will ask you what to do with that, and will ask you if you want to manually set up this or automatically. Don't bother at this time - just choose auto.

Comment: Mount points are folders on your file system, that leads to different physical storage's or pseudo filesystems. For example, you can create folder /net-drive, and mount a network drive to that folder. So that if you look at that folder content, you will see the file list like you usually do on the local drive folder, but in reality the files are located remotely. Same can be done with the partitions from the local drives. Search around here on *askubuntu*, there are plenty of info about this.

Comment: @WarrenHill Thank You for your inputs, that cleared lots of my doubts.
Regarding /home, I already have an extra partition drive G: in Windows where I keep all my personal files so that I can format C: without deleteing files from G:. The G: drive is formatted as NTFS.
Can I use the same drive for saving & using files from Ubuntu?
Or is it recommended to create a /home drive with ext4 format?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs so mount point is like a drive in Windows? like C: drive, D: drive, etc?
Thanks for that info on unallocated space that cleared my main doubt. Thank You.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Although I recommend to have a separate /home partition in long term, you can skip that, if you know you will keep all your files on G: ntfs partition.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Yes, you can think of the point points as it would be drive names in Windows. This is incorrect, but the idea is similar.